# Ruby XML to JSON Converter?

Tags: xml, ruby, json, converters

Is there a library to convert XML to JSON in Ruby?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

A simple trick:

First you need to `gem install json`, then when using Rails you can do:

```
require 'json'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
Hash.from_xml('<variable type="product_code">5</variable>').to_json #=> "{\"variable\":\"5\"}"
```

If you are not using Rails, then you can `gem install activesupport`, require it and things should work smoothly.

**Example:**

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
s = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/ruby/')).body
puts Hash.from_xml(s).to_json
```

Comment: Sometimes it is important to keep the XML attributes as well. For example, in your example above, "product_code" was lost. What library or libraries would you suggest to keep the attributes?

Comment: An update, in case if your running a ruby script for the same as a standalone program to avoid undefined method "from_xml". You need to include require ‘active_support/core_ext’ , as given here:- http://masonoise.wordpress.com/2010/01/07/hash-from_xml/#comments . This works fine in Rails otherwise..

Comment: Small improvement to have pretty-printed JSON:
    `JSON.pretty_generate(Hash.from_xml('<variable type="product_code">5</variable>'))`

Comment: Note you need to `require 'json'` and `require 'active_support/core_ext'` to get Tom De Leu's example to work

Comment: Note you need to require 'json' and 'active_support/core_ext/hash' - NOT 'active_support/core_ext'

Comment: You also need to convert from string to Hash: eval(Hash.from_xml(s).to_json)

Answer (score 26):

I'd use [Crack](http://github.com/jnunemaker/crack), a simple XML and JSON parser.

```
require "rubygems"
require "crack"
require "json"

myXML  = Crack::XML.parse(File.read("my.xml"))
myJSON = myXML.to_json
```

Answer (score 13):

If you wish to keep all attributes I recommend cobravsmongoose http://cobravsmongoose.rubyforge.org/
which uses the badgerfish convention.

```
<alice sid="4"><bob sid="1">charlie</bob><bob sid="2">david</bob></alice>
```

becomes:

```
{"alice":{"@sid":"4","bob":[{"$":"charlie","@sid":"1"},{"$":"david","@sid":"2"}]}}
```

code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cobravsmongoose'
require 'json'
xml = '<alice sid="4"><bob sid="1">charlie</bob><bob sid="2">david</bob></alice>'
puts CobraVsMongoose.xml_to_hash(xml).to_json
```

Answer (score 5):

You may find the [`xml-to-json` gem](https://github.com/digitalheir/ruby-xml-to-json) useful. It maintains attributes, processing instruction and DTD statements.

### Install

```
gem install 'xml-to-json'
```

### Usage

```
require 'xml/to/json'
xml = Nokogiri::XML '<root some-attr="hello">ayy lmao</root>'
puts JSON.pretty_generate(xml.root) # Use `xml` instead of `xml.root` for information about the document, like DTD and stuff
```

Produces:

```
{
  "type": "element",
  "name": "root",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "type": "attribute",
      "name": "some-attr",
      "content": "hello",
      "line": 1
    }
  ],
  "line": 1,
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "content": "ayy lmao",
      "line": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

It's a simple derivative of [`xml-to-hash`](https://github.com/digitalheir/ruby-xml-to-hash).

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for speed I would recommend [Ox](https://github.com/ohler55/ox) since it's pretty much the fastest option from the ones already mentioned.

I ran some benchmarks using an XML file that has 1.1 MB from [omg.org/spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/CWM/20020501/) 
and these are the results(in seconds):

```
xml = File.read('path_to_file')
Ox.parse(xml).to_json                    --> @real=44.400012533
Crack::XML.parse(xml).to_json            --> @real=65.595127166
CobraVsMongoose.xml_to_hash(xml).to_json --> @real=112.003612029
Hash.from_xml(xml).to_json               --> @real=442.474890548
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using libxml, you can try a variation of this (disclaimer, this works for my limited use case, it may need tweaking to be fully generic)

```
require 'xml/libxml'

def jasonized
  jsonDoc = xml_to_hash(@doc.root)
  render :json => jsonDoc
end

def xml_to_hash(xml)
  hashed = Hash.new
  nodes = Array.new

  hashed[xml.name+"_attributes"] = xml.attributes.to_h if xml.attributes?
  xml.each_element { |n| 
    h = xml_to_hash(n)
    if h.length > 0 then 
      nodes << h 
    else
      hashed[n.name] = n.content
    end
  }
  hashed[xml.name] = nodes if nodes.length > 0
  return hashed
end
```

Comment: home-made code solutions are generally a bad idea for generic problems - except for learning purposes.
Especially when the question is specifically an enquiry about an existing library.

Answer (score 2):

Simple but with heavy dependencies (`active_support`); it's not much of a problem if you already are in a Rails environment.

```rb
require 'json'
require 'active_support/core_ext'

Hash.from_xml(xml_string).to_json
```

Else it would be probably better to use `ox` or `rexml` to have much lighter dependencies and more performance.

Comment: It's actually khelll anwser and it requires `active_support` which is a pretty big external dependency to use `from_xml`. `json` is also required for `to_json` even if it's stdlib so we can say native.