# Rails, HTML to JSON?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Given a static HTML page, is there an automated way to generate json?

For a large website that contains a lot of static HTML I am wanting to generate json for RSS feeds and search functionality and am looking for a way to convert HTML to json.

I could obviously write json templates for every page and every language but that would be a unmaintainable. That would double an 800page website to 1600 pages and that is not an option.

One approach I thought of could be to write a bot that would loop through the routes to index the pages and save data to a database which would give me all the choices I could wish for, for searching such as solr, elastic search, thinking sphinx etc...

I could use capybarra to aid me in this by visiting each path and extracting text to save to a database in a rake task as a background job but not sure how that would work in a production environment and it seems that such a common requirement might have already been achieved but for the life of me I can't find one.

I would be far happier (I think) if I could find a way to convert HTML text content to JSON

Any ideas? Has this already been done? are there any gems that might help? or is there built in functionality that I have not thought of, maybe a way to get html into a hash that could then be converted into json? whatever the approach it needs to be automated. I'm just stuck for the best approach.

Comment: What kind of result do you want ? extracting the main things (title, h1, and so on) from an HTML file and putting that in JSON is simple.

Comment: @dystroy That would be a great start and may be all that I need to do

Comment: I don't know ruby but in many languages (Go, JS/node, etc.) parsing the HTML files and extracting those information is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to go with a nokogiri solution in the end and wrote a parser to meet my needs

Answer (score 1):

Basically html looks a lot like xml, but with strong tag meanings, so you could use xml to json conversion, if it all ends up getting tree of html tags embedded in each other.
And so your question becomes [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530324/ruby-xml-to-json-converter) Except you might get problems with single tags, without closing one. So you might get all of these and put a closing bracket after each one before trying to get it as hash from xml.  Oh, early answer. Btw in general for parsing text data you should look at regular expressions.

Comment: Fair enough but how to get html into xml? I appreciate the thoughts and I will probably also want to convert to atom at some point for the RSS feeds but the question remains but slightly changed perhaps to how to get HTML into another format?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I hate regex, It's a programming language in it's own right and very powerful but so damn confusing and complex. Whole books have been written on it and I don't have the time or the inclination to learn yet another tool. There has to be a simpler way? I hope?

Comment: @jamesw i googled a bit and found out that nokogiri is what you want, here's a link to the [parser](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/SAX/Parser.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had thought of nokogiri. I'll take a longer look at it. I think this is a case of not being able to see the trees for the wood.