# Convert html response to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to implement SMS API in rails, when I hit the API url I get following html response:

```
<!DOCTYPE RESULT SYSTEM "http: api_link ">
<html><body>
<result reqid="57469">
    <mid submitdate="2015-12-02 00:51:55" id="1" tag="null" tid="103335">

    </mid>
</result>
</body></html>
```

How can I convert this to `json`?

Comment: How do you print that data to the view?

Comment: I am rendering it in controller only.

Comment: Yes, obviously. Could you post that code as well?

Comment: No, I want to convert it to json so that it could be read by android developer. Depending upon <result> he will show some message to user.

Comment: I just wanted to see if you're passing the data through a hash, because if you are, there's a neat thing called to_json that you could use, http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_json

Comment: Initially I did .to_json but then I realized it works with array not with html,

Comment: I don't believe you can parse html objects to JSON (someone more front end, feel free to correct me), but you have to do it in your Ruby code, preferably in your model and not in the controller.

Comment: Hi @Emmy and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really hard for us to debug a verbal description of your code. We need to see the *actual* code in order to help you. Can you please edit your question and add in all the relevant code (the controller code etc). If you don't do this, then we cannot help you. Note: please don't put code in comments (like here), because the formatting is dreadful - edit your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time you cannot convert html straight to json, but you can convert html to a hash and then the hash to json.

```
YOUR_HTML_CODE = '<!DOCTYPE RESULT SYSTEM "http: api_link "><html><body> <result reqid="57469"> <mid submitdate="2015-12-02 00:51:55" id="1" tag="null" tid="103335"> </mid></result></body></html>'

@data = Hash.from_xml(YOUR_HTML_CODE).to_json
```

Returns:

```
=> "{\"html\":{\"body\":{\"result\":{\"reqid\":\"57469\",\"mid\":{\"submitdate\":\"2015-12-02 00:51:55\",\"id\":\"1\",\"tag\":\"null\",\"tid\":\"103335\",\"__content__\":\"\\n\\n    \"}}}}}"
```

To find more ways to do what you want, search for rails xml to json, you will find more answers [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530324/ruby-xml-to-json-converter). [Crack gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/crack) seems to be [excellent](http://caseyscarborough.com/blog/2013/08/03/dead-simple-xml-and-json-parsing-in-ruby/) for this.

**Note** that if you are using rails you should be handling this on the backend, but that was not as helpful of an answer by itself, thus my answer above.